# How to mod android rom so none can ever install an app in it?

Tags: applications, security, custom-roms

I already know how to modify an android ROM by modifying files, remove and add it into ROM. But I don't have knowledge to building/compiling a ROM.

I want to lock the OS so none can ever install new app to it. Well at least for they that not have a knowledge to flash the ROM with other OS.

Is there a way to prevent user from install any application to the ROM?

like removing the market app or the package installer, pros n cons?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: the boss want it that way :)

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of removing the store and package installer should work.

To do so, delete the following apks (and any .odex files of the same name) from /system/app, either in your ROM image or after obtaining root.

- DefaultContainerService.apk - used for app installs by both the Play store and Packageinstaller.
- PackageInstaller.apk - This is used to install non-market apps.
- Vending.apk - This is the Play store.
- Phonesky.apk - This is the Play store on JB and some ICS builds.

With those gone (and the phone unrooted), it should be impossible to install anything.

Note : I have not tested this.  Making a backup before doing this would be advisable.

Comment: Removing just the PackageInstaller should do. Tried it myself, even play store apps wont install.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way would be with a modded stock ROM. Starting with a full stock ROM, I would do the following:

1. Root the ROM.
2. Install a custom kernel with init.d support.
3. Remove unwanted google apps.
4. Set `/data` to read only. You can do this with a init.d script that remounts the folder: `mount -o remount,ro /data`
5. Remove root.

The only problem is that the user wouldn't be able to save no data. Another aproach might be to change the permisions of `/data/app` folders (app-private and so) to 644 (755 for directories) and change ownership to root. That way the user won't be able to write to the apps folder, but it would be able to save information in the `/data` folder (and subfolders).

If you don't need any google apps, you can use *CyanogenMod* or other Custom ROM that doesn't have anything from Google apps installed.